# My Firebase project has unknown users, has my google cloud service account been compromised?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My project is a flutter app, it is in Internal Testing only, I am the only user. I've been working on this project for about a month and all of a sudden today I keep getting unknown users registering. These unknown users are not registering through my app otherwise I would see additional data in my Firestore database.

The only change I made today that I can think might be related is that I added the release SHA certificate fingerprints to my firebase project settings.

Security measures that I've taken: I changed all my passwords and turned on 2-factor authentication for my google accounts. Did not solve my problem, unknown users continue to be created.

I don't know much about service accounts but maybe my Firebase service account or a google cloud platform service account has been compromised? My Users and Permissions settings page says '10 service accounts also have access to this project.'

Are these accounts being created by google for some reason?

Here's a screenshot of my Auth users, there should only be one.
[image: unknown users]

Comment: You might want to update your screenshot so that the emails of your users do not show up publicly.

Answer (score 2):

These accounts might be created by [Pre-launch reports](https://play.google.com/console/about/pre-launchreports/) by Google bots. I had the same experience, the moment I published an app into Closed testing and enabled all countries these accounts started to appear in my Firebase Authentication Users report.

Try to provide your own Test account credentials in Google Play console under Pre-launch report settings and check if new accounts will still be created.